# Double Submit button on php using switch case

Tags: php, html, submit, form-submit

i have two submit button in form and i used Switch case method to implement the code.
One for SignIn page ie it redirects to another page
other for NewUser page and this one should redirect to another registration page.

but my code is not working and below is the code.

```
<?php

switch($_POST['submit'])
{
case 'SignIn':

    header('Location : http://localhost/eproject/UserPage.php');
    break;

case 'NewUser':
echo "NEw user page resgistri";
    break;

default:
echo "Dont know what you are doing ! ";
break;
}


?>


<table>
<form name="form8" method="post" >
<tr><td>Cutomer Username</td><td><input type="text" name="uname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Customer Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd"</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="SignIn" name="submit"></td><td><input type="submit"         value="NewUSer" name="submit"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? Did you notice you typoed "NewUSer" in the second submit button's name?

Answer (score 0):

`value="NewUSer"`  in the HTML

`NewUser` in the PHP

- note the uppercase `S`

Comment: Thanks!!, but when SignIn button is posted then it should redirects to the UserPage.php, but thats not working. And code for UserPage.php is below `echo $_POST['uname']; echo $_POST['pwd']`

Comment: @Mohammed Uzair Ahmed :: Turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and see what the errors say. Also note that NO browser output can appear before the header() call - otherwise it will not run (this includes <html>, empty lines etc... )

Comment: @Mohammed (without testing, so if im wrong im sorry) the page you are redirecting the user to might not have the post values anymore.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to use a hidden input field like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="thefieldname" value="thevalue" />
```

then you can use the switch statement like this:

```
switch($_POST['thefieldname']){
    case '':
       .....
       break;
}
```

Comment: I assume the OP wants to have the two submit buttons on the form like he has now. You'd have to toggle the hidden field's value with JavaScript instead of using basic HTML form controls. How would this be "better"?

Answer (score 0):

To easily find out mistakes like these (NewUSer instead of NewUser), if the code is not working, first use GET method and check if it is working. If it is not, check all GET variables in the address bar. This will help to make debugging simple.

Answer (score 0):

After a

```
header("location: ....
```

one should always use a

```
die();
```

to avoid having the rest of the script processed.